# How to implement QT(Quality Threshold) Clustering in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, data-science

I want to implement QT clustering in python. I found it is implemented in flexclust package using R programming. Here is the link for more detail on QT clustering https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/quality-threshold-clustering-algorithm-1

Comment: What did you try? You can take a look at the R package and replicate it in python for example.

Comment: try sklearn kmeans clustering.

Comment: @Netwave that is a good idea, I will try it. But if there is any existing package, then it would be great.

Comment: @abhilb  I tried it results were not promising for my use case